# bannerViewDidLoadAd is not called

Tags: swift, iad

iAD delegate never calls, although I set it in viewWillAppear.

in AppDelegate

```
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
```

in ViewController

```
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

 func appdelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - 50, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(10)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0.5
    println("hello")
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

The funny think that adBanner actually show test advertising.

UDP: I did understand what was wrong. To display iAd, all you need is to set `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, thats it. But you don't have any access to delegates of banned that was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you instantiate a `UIiAd` as a property of your app delegate, **and** another `UIiAd` as a property of your viewController.
Then:

```
UIiAd.delegate = self // The viewController's instance gets the delegate assigned
UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd // The viewController's instance changes and becomes the same as the app delegate's instance
```

This is not the way I'm used to deal with iAd, but in your case it might suffice changing the order of two lines of code:

```
UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
UIiAd.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! Thank you, it did actually work. 
I tried before another way

 var bannerView:ADBannerView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.bannerView?.delegate = self
        self.bannerView?.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        bannerView?.hidden = false
        println("banner is loaded")
        
    }

but it didn't work

Comment: following this tutorial http://ashishkakkad.com/2014/10/how-to-add-iad-advertise-banner-view-in-your-application-swift-language-ios-8-xcode-6-gm-tutorial/

Comment: You might also be interested in an early Swift test of mine. It's about an iAd singleton you can place at the top or bottom of a view. [iAdExample](https://github.com/perlfly/iAdExample)

Comment: I already did, I pushed an accept button, did it worked? 
Thank you for your link. Can you tell, if it is possible to push the viewController.view, so its height shrinks? Right now banner overleap view.

Comment: You didn't since we can't see the green tick. If you just need a banner at the bottom, and the view _auto shrinking_, you might be interested in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443149/adbannerview-below-uitableviewcontroller/29443421#29443421) and forget about the other examples